# SPF records should also be published in DNS as type SPF records

Tags: email, domain-name-system, txt-record, spf

I recently set up SPF records for a domain and when I checked the records using http://www.kitterman.com/ I got an error message that stated

```
SPF records should also be published in DNS as type SPF records.
```

In Godaddy there is only an option to add TXT records, and not SPF records, as far as I can tell.

[image: Picture.png]

They do have a link for "Add SPF Record" but it just generates a TXT record. Does Godaddy just not support this or do I not understand what the error message is saying?

Comment: This is probably not one for stackoverflow (superuser perhaps). However, we had a similar issue at work (our DNS provider did not support SPF records). Apparently TXT records may be used to host a SPF record (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework#Principles_of_operation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPF originally used `TXT` records but in IETF circles that was considered bad engineering because `TXT` has become a dumping ground for any old chunk of information and there's no way of knowing when you ask for a `TXT` record whether what you're going to get is an SPF record, something else, or even both.

Hence a formal `SPF` record DNS type was introduced to mitigate those concerns.  If there's no SPF record you'd get back a `NODATA` response, instead of whatever irrelevant TXT records might exist for other purposes at that domain.

However many web DNS panels don't support it, as you've just found.

Comment: Also SPF ressource records was made obsolete by RFC6686.

Comment: @LasseMichaelMølgaard Yes, unfortunately :(